# How to set the NMS Redelivery policy in C#

Tags: nms

I am working with ActiveMQ's NMS client library in C#. I do not understand how to set the Redelivery Policy in code. I have tried to set the property in code on consumer side, but I am not able to understand whether it is working or not.

```cs
RedeliveryPolicy policy = connection.RedeliveryPolicy
policy.InitialRedeliveryDelay = 50000;
policy.MaximumRedeliveries = 5;
```

Above I have set the property, but I don't know it is right way or not.

Comment: Have you tried triggering a redelivery in order to see if the policy is working?

Comment: Can you confirm you're using the NMS API?

Comment: The code looks correct for NMS but the question lacks context on why you think it isn't working

Comment: Have you ever solved this?

Answer (score -1):

It should be connection.getRedeliveryPolicy();

Below is a simple example of settings:

```
RedeliveryPolicy policy = connection.getRedeliveryPolicy();
policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(500);
policy.setBackOffMultiplier(2);
policy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
policy.setMaximumRedeliveries(2);
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? Your example looks like Java code, but the question is about C#.